# java interface avoid casting

Tags: java, interface, casting, implements

I have two classes. An interface class "Node" and "Nodegraph" that implements "Node". "Node" has one parametric method, add, where I use Node node as paramenter. In NodeGraph, I need to casting (NodeGraph) node in order to use NodeGraph object. Is there a better way to avoid casting?

```
import java.util.Set;

public interface Node {
    public String getId();
    public void add(Node node);
    public boolean remove(Node node);
}


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class NodeGraph implements Node {

    private int row;
    private int column;
    private String id;
    private LinkedList<NodeGraph> neighbourds = new LinkedList<NodeGraph>();

    public NodeGraph(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        id = "" + row + column;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Node node) {
        neighbourds.add((NodeGraph) node);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Node node) {
        return neighbourds.remove((NodeGraph) node);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have valid reasons to keep `neighbourds` list bound to `NodeGraph` type. 
If so here is how you can avoid casting by parametrizing the Node interface:

```
public interface Node< T extends Node<T> > {
    public String getId();
    public void add(T node);
    public boolean remove(T node);
}

public class NodeGraph implements Node<NodeGraph> {

    private int row;
    private int column;
    private String id;
    private LinkedList<NodeGraph> neighbourds = new LinkedList<NodeGraph>();

    public NodeGraph(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        id = "" + row + column;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(NodeGraph node) {
        neighbourds.add(node);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(NodeGraph node) {
        return neighbourds.remove(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any performance benefits by avoiding the casting as well? I've seen this type of pattern in Scala, can you recommend some  good resources to look into type bounds for Java?

Answer (score 3):

That happens because you `neighbourds` list is invariant, this means that you could insert the parametrized type only, which is `NodeGraph` in this case, defining the list as covariant to `Node` would let you add any subclass of `Node`:

```
private LinkedList<? extends Node> neighbourds = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the `neighbors` list using the interface (for both `List` and `Node`):

```
private List<Node> neighbourds = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: thanks but I get an error when i change  private LinkedList<NodeGraph> neighbourds = new LinkedList<NodeGraph>(); in private List<Node> neighbourds = new LinkedList<>(); or maybe I didn't get your help

Comment: What seems to be the error? I can only assume it has to do with the "diamond" operator and the language level of your project being 1.6 or below). If so, use `new LinkedList<Node>()` or (far better) upgrade to java8. Also note that you must import `java.util.List` for this to work.